# Is there a deep connection between the urn problem and the sum of powers?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

The urn problem goes as follows: How many ways are there to place $k$ indistinguishable balls into $n$ distinguishable urns? The solution to the problem being $\binom {n+k-1}{k}$ (or $\binom {n+k-1}{n-1}$).
Upon typing the solution into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%2Bk-1+choose+k) I found the following table:
[image]
This table, I noticed, exhibits uncanny similarity to the table of the sums of powers $\sum _{i=1}^{n}i^{k}$:
[image]
My question is, is this similarity accidental, or is there a more deep connection between the two? And if there is such connection, is there an intuitive way of deriving the first from the second and vise versa?

Comment: It breaks down completely for $k=4$ (upper table) so I'm thinking that it's just coincidence. Factors such as $1/2$ and $1/6$ are very common.

Comment: Well, for one thing, some properties of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) are derived using the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), so a connection shouldn't be too surprising. However, this answer doesn't really get at whether there is a deep connection.

Comment: see Bernoulli numbers.